# The Raspberry Pi 4 fails to reboot

Tags: ssh, pi-4, ubuntu, temperature, reboot

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu Server 18.04. I usually SSH into it and reboot the system. However, I noticed that sometimes the pi does not successfully boot up again after shutdown, so I have to go and manually plug it off, then plug it on again. The pi is outdoors, and it is kind of hot outside (around 57 C). I have other pi's indoors and I could not replicate the problem with them, which leads me to think it is a temperature issue. Has anyone experienced this before? I can't have the raspberry pi not rebooting by itself. This needs to be fixed.

Comment: check the logs in `/var/log` to see what's happening

Comment: You can use `vcgencmd measure_temp` to measure arm core clock temperature if that helps.